# jitter the position of point in the line chart when using stat_summary()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 in R to create an interaction plot by making a line chart at the group level. I'd noticed that data points could potentially be overlapped when their values are very close.

This overlapped issue reduces the visibility and precision of each individual data point. Especially, the plot applies error bars and the interaction line that led to more overlapped in a single plot.

I'm wondering is it possible to jitter data points when using `stat_summary()` to create line charts?

Here is the code for an example of the line chart. Noted that I haven't add any error bar in this example.

```
df.test <- data.frame(group=rep(c("DG", "SK"), each=2),
                  dose=rep(c("B", "A"),2),
                  gain=c(1.30, 1.80,0.5, 1.7))

ggplot(data=df.test, aes(x=dose, y=gain, group=group)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point")+  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "line",aes(linetype= group))
```

Expected outocme that error bars are included.

[image]

Any comment is much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look's like adding `position = "jitter"` doesn't work as expected. But you can do this manually by creating a new variable (`x_pos` in my example):

```
library(tidyverse)

df.test %>%
  mutate(
    x_pos = +(dose == 'B'),
    x_pos = if_else(group == 'DG', x_pos - .05, x_pos + .05)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = x_pos,
    y = gain,
    group = group
  )) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = mean,
    geom = "point"
  ) +  
  stat_summary(
    aes(linetype = group),
    fun.y = mean,
    geom = "line"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:1,
    labels = c("A", "B")
  ) +
  xlab("dose")
```